# Weak convergence toward $L^1$ functions

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $K$ be a compact metric space, and $(\mu_N)_{N\geq 1}$ and $\mu$ be probability measures over $K$ such that $\mu_N\Longrightarrow \mu$. For $f$ a continuous function over supp$(\mu)$ such that

$$f\in L^1(K,\mu)\cap\bigcap_{N\geq 1}L^1(K,\mu_N),$$

Do we have $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow+\infty}\int_K f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_N=\int_K f\,\mathrm{d}\mu?$

Comment: Suppose $\mu_N$ is the dirac measure at $1/N$ and $f$ is the indicator of the point 1?